# Two buttons in a row (Bootstrap form theme for Symfony2)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig, symfony2-forms

I'm using [the Bootstrap form theme for Symfony2](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-bootstrap-form-theme) (bootstrap_3_**horizontal**_layout.html.twig):

I've added two buttons on a form:

```
$builder
    // some code here ... 
    ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'save'])
    ->add('cancel', 'submit', ['label' => 'cancel']);
```

And they are rendered this way:
[image]

I need that they be situated on the same row:
[image]

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Maybe needed to change in css.`display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Following the

> [**Symfony Best Practises**: Add buttons in the templates, not in the form
>   classes or the
>   controllers.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#form-button-configuration)

E.g.:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form) }}

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
      <button type="submit" value="cancel" class="btn btn-default">cancel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Is it still possible in controller to know which button was pushed when adding buttons only in templates ? $form->get('save') throws an OutOfBoundsException exception, $form->getData() doesn't have the information anymore. ie: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms

Comment: @Patrick I know your problem, and honestly I tripped over it myself a few times. The purpose of the best practice advice is to keep the form reusable, yet context-sensitive buttons would destory such purpose. If you still need them in the controller (which sometimes really is beneficial), you could for example: a) extend the base form to only add the needed buttons, or b) add the buttons in the controller after creating the form object.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a style float left to the save button. This works for me:

```
    ->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'save', 'attr' => array('style' => 'float: left')])
    ->add('cancel', 'submit', ['label' => 'cancel']);
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you use Bootstrap theme too? I've tried this, but have no result, because of the bootstrap internals - the style is applied to a button tag, but the button by itself is situated in <div class="col-sm-10"> tag, which is created for each button.

Comment: i use the form theming described in the news link you posted and make a simple form with two text field and your two button. Then i render in the template as `{{ form(form) }}`  and use the `{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}` in my page, every button are into a `<div class="form-group">`

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I forgot to inform that I'm using "bootstrap_horizontal_layout.html.twig", in which your recipe somehow doesn't work, but works perfectly with  "bootstrap_layout.html.twig"

Comment: It won't work in applying to buttons. You can set style "display:inline-block;" to both buttons or wrap them with left floated divs.
And as Yoshi suggested below it'sbetter to define submit buttons in templates (but bear in mind it's only recommendation). In template you can much easier manipulate with html elements' attributes.

Answer (score -7):

Have you tried to put the 2nd line on the same line as the first?

Like so:

```
->add('save', 'submit', ['label' => 'save']) ->add('cancel', 'submit', ['label' => 'cancel']);
```

Comment: it's a php code, in php it's irrelevant whether you put it on the same line or not :).

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad.And if you add them to a button group? That might work.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I need group them, but I'm using Symfony2 Form Bundle with Bootstrap form theme for Symfony2 and I don't know yet how to do it within this Bundle.

Comment: This answer made my day. Thanks!